# Force string to be one liner

Tags: python

Do anyone know an alternative ways to  force a string into one liner?
May be a python built-in method?
or perhaps a better implementation (explain why)?

For example:

```
Hello World
Foo Bar
```

Become

```
Hello World Foo Bar
```

### Implementation

```
def strip_newline(s):
    return ' '.join(mystring.splitlines())

strip_newline = lambda _: ' '.join(_.splitlines())
```

### Extra Note:

For those who reminds me about character replacement of `\n`, a line character into . The drawback is you need to watch out for `\r`, carriage return character too. :-)

Thus you need to do `mystring.replace('\r', ' ').replace('\n', ' ')`.

Comment: Will  regex.sub('\n', ' ') perform faster? (I doubt so)

Comment: `'Hello World\nFoo Bar'.replace('\n', ' ')`

Comment: Did it work? What went wrong?

Comment: @tdelaney oh, nothing is wrong. I just curious. I don't satisfy quite easily.

Comment: On *nix, you don't have a carriage return character at the end of your lines.

Comment: @Yeo .. What's wrong with your approach?

Comment: @IronFist nothing is wrong, everything is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

I think simple `replace` would be the fastest method:

```
s = '''
1
2
3
4
5
'''

print (s.replace("\n", " "))
```

Comment: You can't just replace the `\n` itself, you will have to worry about `\r` character. See my question update.

Comment: @Yeo, Yeah, It depends on a file line ending, but generally you're right. However, calling `replace` function twice may negatively impact on performance on long strings

Comment: Note that this will create a new string.

Answer (score 2):

**Performance**

I timed both methods in a bash shell, and it appears that the simple

```
stri.replace("\n", " ")
```

is faster than your proposed solution.

(The file hello.txt is a file containing 1000 lines with the phrase "Hello World".)

```
~$ time python -c 'f = open("hello.txt","r"); stri = f.read(); stri.replace("\n", " ")'

real    0m0.130s
user    0m0.021s
sys     0m0.023s

~$ time python -c 'f = open("hello.txt","r"); stri = f.read(); " ".join(stri.splitlines())'

real    0m0.317s
user    0m0.032s
sys     0m0.028s
```

Alternatively, if you use the `readlines()` method instead of the `read()` method, you can remove the need for your call to `splitlines()` and gain some performance improvement there.

```
~$ time python -c 'f = open("hello.txt","r"); stri = f.readlines(); " ".join(stri)'

real    0m0.176s
user    0m0.033s
sys     0m0.026s
```

**Line Endings**

I'm using linux, so I don't have to worry about the `\r` character. However, in your case, Windows line endings are always of the form `\r\n`, so you can replace your two calls to the `replace()` method

```
stri.replace("\r", " ").replace("\n", " ")
```

with a single call:

```
stri.replace("\r\n", " ")
```

which should also improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

Other approach would be using [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate) method, by building the dictionary of translation (char_to_remove:None mapping) then applying it through `str.translate` :

```
>>> import string
>>> string.whitespace
' \t\n\r\x0b\x0c'
>>> st
'\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n'
>>>
>>> dws = dict.fromkeys(ord(c) for c in string.whitespace)
>>> 
>>> dws
{32: None, 9: None, 10: None, 11: None, 12: None, 13: None}
>>> 
>>> st.translate(dws)
'12345'
```

Of course, this would remove the white space within your string, you can skip this case by conditional comprehension:

```
>>> dws = dict.fromkeys(ord(c) for c in string.whitespace if c != ' ')
```

Or simply:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.linesep
'\n' #on my ubuntu box
>>> st.translate({ord(os.linesep):None})
'12345'
```